# C# syntax with curly brackets

Tags: c#, syntax

On a post on a site I first saw this, previously I only saw it in java. My question is, what is the proper way of writing your curly brackets according to the unspoken rules of programming that everybody always talk about?

**Option A :**

```
If( a==b){
//code here
}
```

**Option B:**

```
If(a==b)
{

//code here

}
```

Are both accepted, or does it just very from person to person.
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the editing I couldnt fix it

Comment: Both are accepted *and* it varies from person to person.

Comment: P.S. apology accepted regarding the typos, but not the spelling errors.

Answer (score 1):

C# code conventions do vary a bit from developer to developer and company to company. However, you've asked a very simple question, so I'll try to give you a bit of insight (below). Learn more on [MSDN with C# Coding Conventions.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)

```
    string a, b, c;
    a = b = c = string.Empty;

    if (a == b)
    {
        //Conventional syntax.
        c = a + b;
    }

    if (a == b)
        // But really, for simple if statements curly braces are not needed.
        c = a + b;

    //Typically you will _not_ see this treatment of curly braces,
    //which is used instead in JavaScript.
    if (a == b) {
        c = a + b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are accepted and you can use with no difference, it's just a matter of user's choice. I normally go with

```
 If(a==b){

}
```

to make it easier to track.